# Fluentd (td-agent) secondary type should be same with primary one error

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

I'm using td-agent with http plugin for sending the log data to another server.
But when start td-agent with my config file, I got the warning message like below,

> 2019-09-06 11:02:15 +0900 [warn]: #0 secondary type should be same
>   with primary one primary="Fluent::TreasureDataLogOutput"
>   secondary="Fluent::Plugin::FileOutput"

Here is my config file,

```
<source>
    @type tail
    path /pub/var/log/mylog_%Y%m%d.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/www_log.log.pos
    tag my.log
    format /^(?<log_time>\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[INFO\] (?<message>.*)$/
</source>

<filter my.log>
    @type parser
    key_name message
    <parse>
        @type json
    </parse>
</filter>

<match my.log>
    @type http
    endpoint_url    http://localhost:3000/
    custom_headers  {"user-agent": "td-agent"}
    http_method post
    raise_on_error  true
</match>
```

It is sending the log data correctly but I need to resolve the warning message too.  How can I resolve the warning?